# Changing Hugo's built-in figure shortcode to add lazy loading to images

Tags: html, hugo, hugo-shortcode

In my Hugo-generated website I'm making use of the built-in shortcode `figure`. Example:

```
{{< figure src="myImage.svg" width="100%" alt="Some description" >}}
```

This renders the following HTML:

```html
<figure>
    <img src="myImage.svg"
         alt="Some description" width="100%"/> 
</figure>
```

But now I'm trying to update my Hugo website in such way that the figure shortcode adds the `loading=lazy` attribute to the `img` tag:

```html
<figure>
    <img 
         loading="lazy"
         src="myImage.svg"
         alt="Some description" width="100%"/> 
</figure>
```

How can I achieve my goal of letting images be loaded lazily using the (new) `loading` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a file named layouts\shortcodes\figure.html and copy the contents of [Hugo's figure shortcode source code](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/master/tpl/tplimpl/embedded/templates/shortcodes/figure.html) into this file. Here's the current source code:

```
<figure{{ with .Get "class" }} class="{{ . }}"{{ end }}>
    {{- if .Get "link" -}}
        <a href="{{ .Get "link" }}"{{ with .Get "target" }} target="{{ . }}"{{ end }}{{ with .Get "rel" }} rel="{{ . }}"{{ end }}>
    {{- end -}}
    <img src="{{ .Get "src" }}"
         {{- if or (.Get "alt") (.Get "caption") }}
         alt="{{ with .Get "alt" }}{{ . }}{{ else }}{{ .Get "caption" | markdownify| plainify }}{{ end }}"
         {{- end -}}
         {{- with .Get "width" }} width="{{ . }}"{{ end -}}
         {{- with .Get "height" }} height="{{ . }}"{{ end -}}
    /><!-- Closing img tag -->
    {{- if .Get "link" }}</a>{{ end -}}
    {{- if or (or (.Get "title") (.Get "caption")) (.Get "attr") -}}
        <figcaption>
            {{ with (.Get "title") -}}
                <h4>{{ . }}</h4>
            {{- end -}}
            {{- if or (.Get "caption") (.Get "attr") -}}<p>
                {{- .Get "caption" | markdownify -}}
                {{- with .Get "attrlink" }}
                    <a href="{{ . }}">
                {{- end -}}
                {{- .Get "attr" | markdownify -}}
                {{- if .Get "attrlink" }}</a>{{ end }}</p>
            {{- end }}
        </figcaption>
    {{- end }}
</figure>
```

After that you can make the required changes to your local figure.html. For instance:

```
...
    <img src="{{ .Get "src" }}" loading="lazy" decoding="async"
...
```

Hugo prefers your locally defined shortcode over its built-in version, meaning that this overrides the built-in behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Render image hooks would be a safe/better bet, then you can keep to standard markdown in your md file.

So, in layouts/_default/_markup (as per whatever lookup order you require, this would be a global setup)

render-image.html

```
<figure>
    <img 
         loading="lazy"
         src=".Destination"
         alt=".Text" width="100%" title=".Title"/> 
</figure>
```

In your markdown file:

```
![]() <- typical markdown image link
```

Docs: https://gohugo.io/templates/render-hooks/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case, I've already overridden that render-image.html for the purpose of lazy loading, but need (or at least: I think I need) the `figure` shortcode as well, because not all images require a width, while I do require the width to be set for certain images. To my knowledge, it's not possible to set the width from within markdown using the `image` markdown syntax.

Comment: No problem, genuinely curious here: Why don't you just get "width"? Why would you need width 100% (like what case)? And if it's certain cases (which I assume it is) jam in an if statement. I believe the point in Markdown is to make it editor capable (i.e. "a person who is an editor, not a dev"). If you then create a uber custom shortcode (which may or may not be needed) then any CMS or someone now a dev updating just got tossed out the window and all of that for a "width: 100%" when you can get the exact  width anyway...
Possibly not salient - but should be noted.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not a great web developer and the width 100% might not be the best solution. There might certainly other solutions that would suit my needs. My needs are to mark certain images in my [blog](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/) (e.g. [this](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/acm/), markdown [here](https://github.com/dotnetjunkie/blog/blob/master/content/posts/ambient-composition-model.md)) to be scaled with the content area (div.post), while other images should be presented as-is. So I think I need a way to differentiate between those images.